# Generate random release name bamboo

Tags: continuous-deployment, bamboo

I'm trying to generate a random release-name by using the Bamboo Server's deployment project / plan.

I was able to generate a dynamic version number by using variables (defined the bamboo.release_number, bamboo.release_major, etc.)

resulting a release name of "**StaticName**-1.2"

I would like to define on each release that the **StaticName** will be generated randomly, based on predefined array or list.
The wanted result is by giving it the list of: ["NameA", "NameB", "NameC"]
Bamboo will generate something else on every run, like:

- "**NameB**-1.3"
- "**NameC**-1.4"
- "**NameA**-1.5"

Any ideas how can I preform such thing?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you can add a build task to write the release name to a file in the project in the format of KEY=VALUE. You would then add an [inject variables task](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/configuring-a-variables-task-687213475.html) to read that file, adding the variables to the plan. You can then reference that variable when creating the release just as you did for the build number.